# Improve a custom regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I've been looking for [*"get everything but"* regex questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-text-that-doesnt-contain-a-word/406408#406408), but I couldn't make it work for my case.
I was trying to get everything except a closing comment `*/`.

I have this expression that gets the me declaration of javascript functions:

```
/(\b(f|F)unction(.*?)\((.*?)\)\s*\{)/g
```

The only problem I found with it at the moment is that it also gets me things such as:

```
function to do whatever */ function demo (el, hop) {
```

Instead of

```
function demo (el, hop) {
```

When having this function declaration with a comment containing the word `function`.

```
/** * recursive function to do whatever */ function demo (el, hop) { /*whatever*/ }
```

This is what I tried so far with no result:

```
/(\b(f|F)unction^((?!\*\/).)*?\((.*?)\)\s*\{)/g
```

Which is basically using what recommending [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/1081396):

```
^((?!hede).)*$  //recommended
^((?!\*\/).)*?  //mine
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Which is basically using what recommending in this post:": I suggest you to read the other answers, in particular the benchmark and ridgerunner answer, because you have choosen the slowest way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
/(\bfunction((?!function).)*\((.*?)\)\s*{)/gi
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gC3wN4/1)

`(?!function)` is a negative lookahead that will match next character only if there is no `function` keyword. Check my demo for your examples.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will find most function declarations, including those for anonymous functions.

```
/\s?function(\s+\w+)?\s*\([^\)]*\)/i
```

Nice tool for testing regexes: https://regex101.com/

Comment: Doesn't seem to get all: https://regex101.com/r/nS6bO7/1 in comparison with https://regex101.com/r/nS6bO7/2